# Can I omit the non-vendor-prefixed CSS properties on mobile sites?

Tags: css, webkit

For a mobile site, do I really need to specify **both** prefixed and non-prefixed CSS property names?

For example:

```
-webkit-background-size:1em; /* absolutely mandatory */
background-size:1em;         /* a useless redundancy */
```

Is there any mobile browser whatsoever that will ignore -webkit properties and only consider the non-prefixed ones? I want to get rid of all non-prefixed attributes to shorten and clear the CSS code.

PS: most phones in third world countries sold with Android 4.1 don't even parse the non-prefixed properties, they still require the -webkit prefix. Another reason to remove the non-prefixed ones.

Comment: Keep your site as much cross-browser as possible. Mobiles uses Firefox/Opera/Chrome/Safari browsers as desktop computers plus it's native browsers.

Comment: Shouldn't the point be getting rid of the prefixed attributes instead of the non-prefixed ones? I understand they are necessary right now, but maybe the focus of the question is on the wrong point

Comment: As long as you're certain your site will never be used in the future, or by any phones that don't currently exist, that's a totally sound direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don’t know of any resource that tracks support of CSS properties in *all* mobile browsers (there are a lot of mobile browsers), so it’s difficult to confirm whether there’s any browser that no longer supports the prefixed versions.

I would note that, specifically regarding `background-size`, it looks like support for the non-prefixed versions came in pretty quickly, and that there aren’t many browsers that required the prefix: http://caniuse.com/#search=background-size.

The current idea is that at some point in the future, support for the prefixed versions of the properties will be dropped. See, for example, this WebKit mailing list post from May 2013:

> We will continue to support the prefixed properties for some amount of time, decided on a case-by-case basis.
>
> https://lists.webkit.org/pipermail/webkit-dev/2013-May/024850.html

It may be a long time before this happens, or it may never happen. But as time goes on, the probability of it happening increases, and the number of people still using browsers that require the *prefixed* versions goes down.

Given that by removing the *non-*prefixed versions you’ll only be removing one line, it doesn’t seem to me like a big gain in shortness or clarity in exchange for the potential future breakage.

I’d suggest initially writing your CSS *without* the prefixed versions, then looking at the browser stats for your site to see which prefixed versions you really need. For some prefixed features (e.g. gradients), maybe older browsers can live without them.

Answer (score 1):

The redundancy in this case is not useless. Older mobile browsers that don't support the standard `background-size` but that do support `-webkit-background-size` will still render. Newer versions of the browser will likely deprecate the `-webkit` prefixed property but will support both the prefixed property value `-webkit-background-size` and the non-prefixed standardized property `background-size`. In this case, the last value specified will be the value used so yes the mobile browser will ignore the `-webkit` prefixed property in favor of the standardized property.

Be mindful that future browsers will probably remove deprecated values. In this case the prefixed property would no longer be supported and the site's styles would break. To ensure, current and future functionality it is a good idea to use both versions for now. When you no longer need to support older versions of the browser, you should drop the ***prefixed version*** in favor of the non-prefixed standardized version. The non-prefixed property is the CSS standard and should never be dropped in favor of the vendor specific prefixed property.